# Compare two columns in separate sheets, GoogleSheet

Tags: javascript

I am looking since 1 week to code a macro in a googleSheet to compare two different columns in different spreadsheets. I am coding in Javascript in the GoogleScript editor.

These two columns are filled with id numbers and they can have different length. On the first sheet the column is [A] and on the second one it is [E].
If some ID in the columns [E] are not in the column [A] i want to add the ID at the bottom of [A] with some information of the same ID row.

Here is my code with some comments because it is little bit complex.
I don't understand why it is not working.
Any help will be much appreciated.

```
function onOpen() {  
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  

 // move from sheet to sheet begining after the Sheet 2
 for(var a = 2; ss.getSheets()[a];a++){  
    var lastRow = ss.getSheets()[a].getLastRow();  
    var lastCol = ss.getSheets()[a].getLastColumn();  

    //Move from row 1 to bottom in the other sheets  
    for (var j = 1; i <= lastRow; j++){  

      // Move from row 1 to bottom in the MASTER TABLE  
      for ( var i = 1; j <= ss.getSheets()[1].getLastRow() ; i++){  

       //Cell [E2], [E3] ...                                  cell [A2], [A3] ...
      if (ss.getActiveRange()[E,i].getValue() == ss.getSheets()  [1].getActiveRange()[A,j].getValue() ){  
         break       // If == then out of the loop and go to i=i+1  
       }else{  
         j = j + 1; // if != then stay with [E,i] but compare to [A,j+1]  
       }  

    // if this [E,i] isn't in the column [A] then it add a row and insert the following values to this new row  
    //this will add a new row and paste the values form sheet(a) in range [A] to  [D]  
    ss.getSheets()[1].insertRowAfter(lastRow-1).appendRow(ss.getSheets()  [a].getSheetValues(i, 5 ,1, 4));  

    // this will add an information form sheet(a).colomn 52 in the cell [F,lastRow-1]  
    // It will overwrite when passing to the next sheet but OK  
    ss.getSheets()[1].getRange(lastRow-1,5,1,1).appendRow(ss.getSheets()[a].getSheetValues(i, 52 ,1, 1));  

   // This will add an information form sheet(a).column 54 in the cell [a+4,lastRow-1]  
   // a is 2,3,4 ... And will paste in columns 6,7,8... ([F],[G],[H]) this is why [a+4]  
   ss.getSheets()[1].getRange(lastRow-1,a+4,1,1).appendRow(ss.getSheets()[a].getSheetValues(i, 54 ,1, 1));  

    }
  }
}
```

}

Comment: You can at the least format the code rather just pasting it?

Comment: Hi, i am totally new to Stackoverflow even if i search on it for weeks. I tried to make it as pretty as possible now. Sorry of the inconvenience.